# How to make my bot not say @everyone, @here or @mention

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

Im making a say command for my bot but how do I make it so it doesnt say @everyone, @here or @ mention

ex:
!say @everyone
the bot will say @everyone which pings how do I make it so it doesnt ping?

the code:

```
var arg= message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
if(!arg){
message.channel.send('What do you want me to say?')
} else
message.channel.send (arg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const newMessage = arg.replace(/<@[!&]?\d+>/, '[mention]');
```

Comment: ok that works for @ mention but not for @ everyone and @ here please help thank you @Lioness100

Answer (score 0):

Replace `var arg= message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")` with `var arg= message.cleanContent.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

Found a simpler way:

```
const Util = require('./node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js');
const msg = Util.removeMentions(arg);
message.channel.send(msg);
```

Refer to: [here](https://support.glitch.com/t/trying-to-disable-everyone-here-and-role-pings-in-say-command/30188).